# How to set programmatically multiple arguments for views contextual filters

Tags: views

How to set programmatically multiple arguments for views contextual filters?

I can do it with one argument, it works great, but not with multiple arguments.

I want to select all nodes created by a list of people, but views only takes first in array into consideration:

```
$array = array(3250,32);
$view = views_get_view('myview');
$view->set_display("myblock");
$view->set_arguments($array);
$view->pre_execute();
$view->execute();
$content = $view->render();
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11):

First you should set this option:
View → Advanced → Your Contextual Filter → More → Allow Multiple Values. 
Then when passing array should be with '+', so, your example:

```
$array = array('3250+32');
$view = views_get_view('myview');
$view->set_display("myblock");
$view->set_arguments($array);
$view->pre_execute();
$view->execute();
$content = $view->render();
```

Comment: What hook would you use to implement this...hook views_pre_view?

Comment: The questioner asked for multiple contextual filters, not one multi-valued contextual filter.

Answer (score 6):

If you're simply looking to render the view with its arguments (and don't need to do any more work on it), you can just call [views_embed_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7).  It's called like so:

```
<?php print views_embed_view($view, $display, $arg1, $arg2, ...); ?>
```

The $view and $display are the machine names of same.  See the above-linked documentation for details.

Comment: views_get_view_result works the same :
views_get_view_result($view, $display, $arg1, $arg2, ...);

Comment: views_get_view_result returns an array of each view item as an object.

Answer (score 1):

Another one approach, which proved to be quite useful:

```
$array = array('3250', '32'); 
$view = views_get_view('myview');
$view->set_display("myblock");
$view->pre_execute($array);
$view->execute();
$content = $view->render();
```

`pre_execute()` method of view object accepts arguments, that will be passed to corresponding contextual filters. E.g. `'3250'` will be passed to the first contextual filter, `'32'` - to the second one.

More info about method [here](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/views/tree/includes/view.inc#n1378).

Comment: Please add some explanation to the code shown in this answer. Not doing so puts your answer at risk of being deleted as a low quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your view is looking for integer values here?   try this:

`$array = array('3250','32'));`

Answer (score 0):

Also you can replace this `$array = array(3250,32);` to `$array = array('3250,32');`

Comment: As far as I know view accept multiple values for contexual filters only in this formats 'id1+id2' or 'id1,id2'. Just try.